# Why does the variance of the Empirical Transfer Function Estimate not decay with increased sample points?

Tags: discrete-signals, noise, power-spectral-density

Please refer to Ljung's Lemma 6.1.

In short, this lemma tells us that for a given LTI system $y[n]=g[n]*u[n]+v[n]$ where $v[n]$ is a stationary stochastic process with a zero-mean and a finite power spectrum $S_{v}(e^{j\Omega})$, then assuming $u[n]$ and $v[n]$ are uncorrelated we can deduce some important properties regarding the variance of the ETFE which I denote as $\widehat{G}(e^{j\Omega})$.

Originally, we define ETFE as $\displaystyle\widehat{G}\triangleq\frac{Y_{N}(e^{j\Omega})}{U_{N}(e^{j\Omega})}=G(e^{j\Omega})+\frac{\mathcal{R}_{N}(e^{j\Omega})}{U_{N}(e^{j\Omega})}+\frac{V_{N}(e^{j\Omega})}{U_{N}(e^{j\Omega})}$ and we know by Ljung's Lemma that $\mathbb{E}[V_{N}(e^{j\Omega})]=0$ so the last term doesn't really matter.

Ljung asserts in his lemma that the discrepancy $\mathcal{R}_{N}$ will either decay if $u[n]$ is non-periodic (I believe it decays at a rate of $1/\sqrt{N}$ as Ljung used the DFT definition that is distinguishable by the scaling term $1/\sqrt{N}$)  or will be exactly $0$ if periodic.

Moreover, he asserts that the variance would be defined as:
$$
\operatorname{var}(\widehat{G}(e^{j\Omega}))=\displaystyle\frac{1}{|U(e^{j\Omega})|^{2}}[S_{v}(e^{j\Omega})+\rho_{2}(N)]$$
where $\rho_{2}(N)$ is some decaying factor with a rate of $1/\sqrt{N}$. The periodogram $|U(e^{j\Omega})|^{2}$ can be thought of as some energy quantity and so the underlying issue is that the ratio:
$$
\text{Noise-to-Signal Power}=\frac{S_{v}(e^{j\Omega})}{|U(e^{j\Omega})|^{2}}
$$
does not decay for non-periodic signal, why is this the case when we know that for a periodic input, the periodogram decays by a factor of $(\sqrt{N})^{2}=N$?

So for non-periodic signals increasing the number of points I sample does not help decreasing variance why is this the case?

Comment: "Please refer to Ljung's Lemma 6.1" Please _edit your question_ to properly cite the work (presumably a book).  If the work is freely available on the web, link to the relevant text.  If it is a paper book, then it would be fair use to quote a paragraph or two to put things into context.

Comment: If $u[n]$ is periodic over $N$ points, then $U(e^{j\Omega})$ will only have $N$ non-zero points.  I this means that you can only get information about $G(e^{j\Omega})$ at those frequencies, with no information in between.  Are you sure that the lemma doesn't say that with an increasing sample duration the discrepancy $\mathcal R$ will decrease, but it will asymptotically approach some non-zero value, instead of asymptotically approaching zero?